# How to restart Unity on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I have Ubuntu 11.04 on my laptop. Unity sometimes crashes. How I can restart Unity using hotkeys?

Comment: What's caused so many people to ask SU questions on SO lately? :\

Comment: I second that. Restart the X Server Ctrl+Alt+Backspace.

Answer (score 3):

Restart the X Server: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>